# Load vue component (truly) dynamically from local file

Tags: vue.js, plugins, electron, components

Is it possible to load a vue component dynamically at runtime (in an electron app to build a plugin system)?

- The component is in a specific file
- Its path is only known at runtime
- The component can either be precompiled (if that is possible, don't know) or is compiled at runtime
- A simple example component is listed below

I tried the following approaches, both failing:

1. Require component

   ```
   <template>
     <component :is="currentComp"></component>
   </template>

   <script>
   ...
   methods: {
     loadComponent(path) {
       const dynComp = eval('require(path)'); // use eval to prevent webpackresolving the require
       this.currentComp = dynComp;
     }
   },
   ...
   </script>
   ```

   The import works, but the line `this.currentComp = dynComp;` Fails with error message:

   `Error in data(): "Error: An object could not be cloned."`
2. Using the code presented [here](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/), but replace url with a local path

   Fails with error message:

   ```
   Failed to resolve async component: function MyComponent() {
     return externalComponent('/path/to/Component.vue');
   }
   Reason: TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise #<Promise>
   ```

The used example component is the following:

```js
// Example component
module.exports = {
  template: `
  <div>
    <input v-model="value"/>
    <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
    <div>{{ value }}</div>
  </div>`,
  name: 'Example',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value(value) {
      console.log('change!');
    },
  },
  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.value = '';
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Create the vue component as a [SFC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) in a separate file (here `src/Component.vue`). I didn't try, but probably it works for inline components, too.
2. Precompile the component using [vue-cli-service](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html), which is already a dev dependency, if the project is created using [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org) (It's nice to use vue-cli here, since the required loaders are already included):

   ```
   yarn vue-cli-service build --target lib src/Command.vue
   ```

   The component is compiled to different bundle types in the `dist` directory. The file `[filename].umd.min.js` can be imported now.
3. Import the component dynamically at runtime:

   ```js
   let MyComponent = eval(`require('/absolute/path/to/[filename].umd.min.js')`);
   Vue.component('MyComponent', MyComponent);
   ```

   The `require` is wrapped inside an `eval` to prevent webpack of trying to include the import in its bundle and transforming the `require` into a `webpack__require`.
4. (Optional) If the SFC component contains a `<style>...</style>` tag, the resulting css is compiled to a separate file. The css can be inlined in the js file by adding the following lines to the `vue.config.js` in the components project root:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     ...
     css: {
       extract: false,
     },
   };
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably look into async loading:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

and see this for a webpack lazy load example:

https://vuedose.tips/dynamic-imports-in-vue-js-for-better-performance/#the-meat%3A

These are just some things I would research for your requirements.

Comment: I have already read about this, but there the components are already known at compile time and bundled with webpack.

Comment: Then you could go for a web component approach. See https://medium.com/@kitson.mac/register-custom-element-dynamically-in-the-dom-with-custom-element-register-package-985f8284bcd